# Error when connecting to WebSocket Server from Client

Tags: python, websocket, webserver

I am trying to establish a connection to a web server through Websocket using Python. However, I constantly am unable to do so as I keep getting the error: **[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed**

Any idea what went wrong? And how I can fix this issue. Thank you.

This is my client.py code which is suppose to connect to the web server though websocket:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from websockets.sync.client import connect


def connection():
    with connect("ws://http://<ip address>") as ws:
        ws.send("Hello world!")
        message = ws.recv()
        print(f"Received: {message}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connection()
```

This are the error messages:

```
line 14, in <module>
    connection()

line 7, in connection
    with connect("ws://http://<ip address>/") as ws:

line 247, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection(

line 824, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):

line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Edit:
I solved the issue. I forgot to map:

```
<ip address> <hostname>
```

in my /etc/hosts file in windows. Once I added it, it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The "getaddrinfo failed" message means that the hostname was not able to be resolved. Looking at the example here https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, you shouldn't need to add the "http://" string into the URL too. Their example shows the following to connect:

```
def hello():
with connect("ws://localhost:8765") as websocket:
    websocket.send("Hello world!")
    message = websocket.recv()
    print(f"Received: {message}")
```

Comment: Hi, however I am trying to connect to a HTTP website which is not hosted on my local machine so I've been trying to figure that out instead

Comment: Websockets and HTTP are completely separate protocols, so you can't use both in the same connection. Does the website that you are attempting to connect to support Websockets?

Comment: Yes, it does support Websocket and its hosted as a public website which I why I am still unable to understand how come the code does not work..